# Implement ASP.NET MVC login that authenticates user using api/web request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity

**Background**

I've been tasked with building a portal for my clients customers that provides them access to information regarding their accounts, fees/balances,
messages etc. Customers information is managed through my clients finance software and is exposed through an API. All CRUD operations are performed via this API. I've implemented a class that builds and executes each web request, deserializes and handles
the request response and returns the result to the MVC Controller which then updates the UI accordingly.

**Problem**

The problem i'm currently facing is implementing a secure login. I plan to use identity to authenticate customers that have accounts within my clients finance
software. The issue is authentication has to happen via the API as opposed to a database. The API will return a token that is attached to each subsequent request.
All examples i've looked at to date authenticate users using a database. How can I setup identity and configure it to use an API as opposed to a database as a data
datasource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going down [ASP.NET Identity](https://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity)/[Identity Server](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3) route is the best option, but if you want to... here is an other option

You could get the token and store in Form Cookie and validate/pull user information on every request.

//add the token to response cookie

```
public ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
{
    var token = _api.Authenticate(username, password);
    //not only token you could store any user information (Name), you have to serialize it 

    var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, email, DateTime.UtcNow, DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1), false, token, _formsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

    var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket))
            {
                Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath,
                Secure = false,
                HttpOnly = false,
                Domain = null,
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1)
            };

    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

//get token information from `HttpContext`

```
var authCookie = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as FormsIdentity;

var token = authCookie.Ticket.UserData

if(authCookie.IsAuthenticated)
{
    // do something....
}
```

add this to `web.config`

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms"/>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring to documentation from [Overview of Custom Storage Providers for ASP.NET Identity](https://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity)

> ASP.NET Identity is an extensible system which enables you to create
>   your own storage provider and plug it into your application without
>   re-working the application.

You can implement your own provider that talks to the web api instead of directly to a database.

Comment: Looks interesting. I'll definitely look it over. Thank you.

Comment: Found a nice article here https://blog.markjohnson.io/exorcising-entity-framework-from-asp-net-identity/ where they remove EF from the picture to connect to another database. If you replace their custom database code with talking to your API it should get you to where you want to go